# How can I resolve Laravel routing problems on a shared server after deployment?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, hosting, web-hosting

I've been working on a Laravel project using a Bootstrap template, and everything works perfectly locally. However, as soon as I deployed my project on a shared server, I encountered a routing issue.

Specifically, when I load the homepage, everything works fine. However, when I click on navbar links to access sections like "About" or "Services," I get a 404 error. Interestingly, when I place the controller for "Services" or "About" in the route of the homepage, the page displays correctly.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

I've checked the following:

> Controllers and views are in the appropriate directories.

> My routes are correctly defined in the web.php file.

> I'm using the route() function to generate URLs.

Answer (score 1):

when you run locally, its served and root dir is in public, but if you dont artisan serve it, it need to add root_dir"/public/"your_routes to access it